# Not able to list files inside a HDFS directory eventhough i have read access to directory

Tags: linux, hdfs

As per below command it clearly states that the user sp10 has read access to input_files directory which is inside /data/staged/advance/adobe/mail_segments/

Why is it the user sp10 not able to list all files inside /data/staged/advance/adobe/mail_segments/input_files  ?

sp10 is one of the users of group cldusers

```
 [sp10@client01 scripts]$ hdfs dfs -ls /data/staged/advance/adobe/mail_segments/
 Found 1 items
 drwxr-----   - appid cldusers          0 2017-06-12 11:12 /data/staged/advance/adobe/mail_segments/input_files


 [sp10@client01 scripts]$ hdfs dfs -ls /data/staged/advance/adobe/mail_segments/input_files
 ls: Permission denied: user=sp10, access=READ_EXECUTE, inode="/data/staged/advance/adobe/mail_segments/input_files":appid:cldusers:drwxr-----


 [sp10@client01 scripts]$ groups sp10
 sp10 : sp10 managers cldusers 


 [sp10@client01 scripts]$ groups appid
 appid : appid managers cldusers
 [sp10@client01 scripts]$
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. If you feel its on-topic elsewhere, then [ask for a migration](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apache Hadoop [HDFS Permissions Guide](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html) includes a section on [Permission Checks](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsPermissionsGuide.html#Permission_Checks), which lists various file system operations and the exact permissions required on the paths.  The relevant operation in this case is `getListing`.  For the final component of the path, this operation requires both read and execute access.  For a user with only read access, it's insufficient, so access is denied.

I expect if you add execute access for the group on /data/staged/advance/adobe/mail_segments/input_files, then it will work the way you want.